# Isothermal expansion of an ideal gas calculated two ways

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider the following problem:

> $\pu{1.0 mol}$ of a monoatomic ideal gas is expanded from state 1 to state 2 as shown in the figure. The magnitude of the work done for the expansion of gas from state 1 to state 2 at $\pu{300 K}$ is ..... $\pu{J}$.  (Nearest integer)
>
> [image: State diagram showing curve from State 1 (6.0 pascals, 22.7 litres) down to State 2 (3 pascals)]
>
> (Given: $R=8.3 \,\mathrm {J\,K^{-1}\,mol^{-1}}$, $\ln 10 = 2.3$, $\log 2 = 0.30$)

I tried to solve this question with 2 methods but my answers were different.

1. I used the equation for isothermal processes
   $$  w = 2.303nRT\log(v_2/v_1) \tag{1} $$
   Considering $v_2$, $p_2$ (final volume and pressure) and $v_1$, $p_1$ as initial. Solving this way I got $\pu{1718.1 J}$.
2. It's simply that I substituted $nRT$ in the above equation as $p_1V_1$ as $p_1V_1 = p_2V_2= nRT$ at constant temperature (isothermal). My answer came to be around $\pu{9397 J}$.

I'm not sure what I did wrong. Is my concept wrong?

Comment: Show us the steps. If the term $\ln \frac{V_2}{V_1}$ was used in both, and the numerical value of the factor you are multiplying with is the same, you should get the same answer.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised you have a correction factor of 2.303 in there, given that you are using the natural logarithm.

Comment: I mistyped I'm sorry. It's actually w=2.303nRTlog(V2/V1). The steps: since process is isothermal so T constt and work= 2.3×1×8.31×300 ×0.3 = 1720J (approx).   Method 2 : P1=6 bar v1=22.7 so W=p1v1×2.3×log2=93.97 bar-L. To convert to J ×100 so 9397 J

Comment: Four questions. First, the expansion looks isothermal. Is it ? Nobody mentions it.  Second, the curve should be a hyperbola. It is not. Why ? Third, P1 = 2·P2. Can we derive that V2 = 2·V1 ? Fourth, how can the volume of 1 mole gas be 22.7 L at 300 K  and 6 bar ?

Comment: The given data are wrong. I explain. The state 1 is : n = 1 mol, P = 6 bar, T = 300K, V = 22.7 L. With these values, the product pV (= 6 10^5 ·0.0227 = 13620 J ) is not equal to nRT (= 8.314 300 = 2494 J).  pV is 6 times too high !.

Comment: @Maurice That is the correct answer. Do you mind posting it? Or maybe the question will be closed before anyone has a chance to post an answer, which would make sense as well.

Comment: What is the correct answer ? My calculated $pV$ or my calculated $nRT$, as both are VERY different ? How should I know ?